# Minor Illusion as communication means

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

Can you do that? I mean, it can produce a whisper-volume sound, but how long or articulate would that be? The intended use is to send a message across the room to another player without NPCs noticing.

Comment: Is it necessary that the NPCs do not notice the communication or would it be enough if they do not understand it?

Comment: added an answer to the duplicate question that might interest you..